# How to handle null in chart

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a chart where the data might be null depending on insufficent input. How would I do to make the chart return in a non error state when I don't have any data?

I could always fake a value but that seems odd to have to do that. I tried setting the linemodel to null but that didn't help. Should this be handled in the xhtml or in java code?

The problem I have is

```
javax.servlet.ServletException
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:667)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.primefaces.component.chart.renderer.LineRenderer.encodeData(LineRenderer.java:36)
    org.primefaces.component.chart.renderer.BasePlotRenderer.render(BasePlotRenderer.java:29)
    org.primefaces.component.chart.ChartRenderer.encodeScript(ChartRenderer.java:98)
```

The code for the linemodel

```
@PostConstruct
    public void collectData() {

        lineModel = new LineChartModel();
        ELContext elContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getELContext();
        MovingAverage movingAverage = (MovingAverage) elContext.getELResolver().getValue(elContext, null, "movingAverage");
        movingAverage.fetchMovingAverageForInstrument();
        LineChartSeries series1 = new LineChartSeries();


        series1.setLabel("MA 16");


        List<MovingAverageAsset> listMAA16;

        List<MovingAverageAsset> listMAA = movingAverage.getListMAA();
        if (listMAA == null) {
            return;
        }
```

Everything is updated from a button

```
<p:chart id="myChart" type="line" model="#{movingAverageChart.lineModel}" style="height:300px;"/>


            <p:commandButton value="Update"
                actionListener="#{movingAverageChart.collectData()}"
                 update=":listForm"/>
```

Comment: Does it need the empty LineChartSeries added to the model?

Comment: No, you mean reshuffling the code so that all data fetch is done first and just the chart init is done?

Comment: It seems you never add the empty series1 to the lineModel. If that does'nt work you could always have a rendered-attribute on the p:chart, which check a property on the bean. And show the text "No data" or something else instead